# Calculate Z-Score from Probability Value - R programming

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I know Z-score can be calculated using `pnorm(q=1, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE)` for example

 That will give us a probability value of `0.841344746068543`

I was wondering if there was a function that calculates the inverse of that to find the probability from the Z score (Calculating Z=1 from the probability value of 0.841344746068543). Some math textbooks call that function it inverse phi.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, its called `qnorm`

```r
qnorm(p=0.841344746068543)
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

In general, for a given distribution there is the following family of functions (using **norm** as example):

1. rnorm - draw random numbers from the distribution
2. dnorm - the density at a given point in the distribution
3. qnorm - quantile function
4. pnorm - distribution function (which you have used)

You have the same set for **unif** for example, (the uniform distribution) (dunif,runif,punif,qunif)